# Nginx seg faults on request to index

Tags: magento2, nginx, hhvm

I am running magento v2.X with Nginx and HHVM, making requests directly to HHVM works fine, and non-magento sites run fine too, but when I make a request to nginx for out of the box magento nginx seg faults and crashes.  My only location block in nginx is a `proxy_pass` to hhvm.  And otherwise I have a very stock Nginx config.  Why would it be seg faulting?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Magento 2.x is not supported to run on hhvm